# Is there any way to know if payment was successful or not when using Buy Now without API

Tags: paypal

We want to use Buy Now button HTML code and not use API.  I see there is way to specify auto return URL. However, is there any way to know whether payment was successful or payment failed with error when control is returned from Paypal to our website ?  Reason I am asking this question is , we are not sure what message to show to User when he/she returns from Paypal website.  We can't say "Thank you for the purchase" when payment actually fails.

How would you handle it without API.

Comment: Specify a cancel_url as well as a return_url. They can be the same, with different arguments to show whether he user paid or cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/&ei=JnxRU-D7Cs2vyASo4YLwAg&usg=AFQjCNEqTZjFO4LiVj479Ti46srd-Pk00Q&bvm=bv.65058239,d.aWw) on your backend. This will allow you to get notifications of events related to PayPal transactions.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. That's basically the whole point of the API, to allow you to receive information from PayPal. If you are just using a "dumb" button, you have no way to know what occurred.

Comment: What I know from `Paypal` When the purchase is made `Paypal` will notify you by calling an URL. Could you give an example of an API who can tell you what happened?